# iOS unable to update calendar event when synced to exchange account

Tags: ios, email, calendar, duplicates, exchange-server

i'm having an issue updating a calendar event on my ipad with an exchange email account on it.  it'll create new events no problem, but on an update, it'll create another one, instead of updating the existing.  a few things

- code below works for any other type of email account (say gmail)
- code below works if i don't have an email (so it just writes to the local calendar)
- yes i've checked that my exchange email has calendars enabled

the error being thrown is:

```
Error getting event with identifier 9E678016-F8E4-46B1-9043-E54E09A148F0:5A89FFAF15B1408386A9CBD518BBDD770: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1010
```

here is the code that i'm using.

```
 [self.eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (granted) {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSString *appleEventId = [item valueForKey:@"appleEventId"];
            EKEvent *currentEvent = [self.eventStore eventWithIdentifier:[item valueForKey:@"appleEventId"]];
            if (currentEvent){
                NSLog(@"LOG101: found an event with %@",appleEventId );
                [self createEvent:currentEvent inEventStore:self.eventStore forActivity:item];
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"LOG101: COULD NOT FIND an event with %@",appleEventId );
                EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:self.eventStore];
                [self createEvent:event inEventStore:self.eventStore forActivity:item];
            }
            completionHandler(YES);
        });
    }
    else{
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        completionHandler(NO);
        });
    }
}];
```

(create event does a bunch of customer logic, but ultimately calls the following to create an event)

```
  [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

it's frustrating because the code works for everything else but exchange. any tips / suggestions would be great. thanks

Comment: update: it seems like when i create a new event and have it added to my exchange calendar, the event identifier it modified shortly after it is synced to the server. is any one else having this problem? (i feel like it can't just be me...)

Answer (score 0):

I've been pulling hairs for two days over a similar problem!

The documentation for eventIdentifier states:

"If the calendar of an event changes, its identifier most likely changes as well."
https://developer.apple.com/reference/eventkit/ekevent/1507437-eventidentifier?language=objc

Also the documentation for calendarIdentifier states:

"A full sync with the calendar will lose this identifier. You should have a plan for dealing with a calendar whose identifier is no longer fetch-able by caching its other properties."
https://developer.apple.com/reference/eventkit/ekcalendar/1507380-calendaridentifier?language=objc

I thinks it's safe to say you can't rely on saving calendar or event identifiers locally for later use if the calendar is synchronised :-(